# Windows Search alias

Tags: windows, search, alias

I have a program that I used to use all the time. Now however a new one has superseded it. However I constantly forget it's name, and when searching for it using the windows search, I keep using the outdated name.

I want to know if there is a way for me to add an alias to the new file so that when I type the old files name into the search bar it pops up with the new one without having to actually change it's name.

So I search "Old Name" and windows would show two options.

1. "Old Name"
2. "New Name"

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you use it all the time then why don't you simply find it once and then right click and "pin to taskbar" or "pin to start menu" so you always know where it is?

Comment: Or create a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's not something that I use a lot. It would clutter up the taskbar by doing that. Also it is no where near as elegant. 
Now it comes up as "New Program name (Old Program Name)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an alias to the Start Menu can be done this way :

- Open Explorer to the folder
  `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- Right-click any white-space inside the folder and select
  *New > Shortcut*
- Answer the question of
  "What item would you like to create a shortcut for?" with the full path
  to your program
- Use the old name for answering the question of
  "What would you like to name the shortcut?"
- Click Finish.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. Thank you for the help!